# Getting values from a specific data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to set up a tracking system that uses a data value for holding an event type. My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#articles" class="track" data-track="article_search_results">Articles</a>
<a href="#books" class="track" data-track="books_search_results">Books</a>
<a href="#notes" class="track" data-track="notes_search_results">Notes</a>
```

And the JQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).delegate('.track', 'click', function(e) {   
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).data("track")); 
});
```

Using every element that has the class .track, I'm trying to get the data-track value from it, but it always returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have icons in my code which is causing the problem:

```
<a href="#articles" class="track" data-track="article_search_results"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kJbjL/

Comment: It does work without the icon..not sure why that is a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
           $(document).delegate('.track', 'click', function(e) {   
                console.log($(this).attr("data-track")); 
           });
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FZEKC/

Comment: Figured out what the problem is, code is fine by the syntax with an icon isn't

Comment: Glad you have figured out the issue yourself

Comment: No, the issue still exist, just figured out the problem

Comment: why you dont assign the class to anchor instead of <i> tag? try this one `<a href="#articles" class="track icon-pencil" data-track="article_search_results"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Using `attr`, you can return the `data-track` value from an element, for example:

**Code:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.track', function(e) {   
    var dataTrack = $(this).attr("data-track");
});
```

*According to the jQuery docs, `delegate` has been superseded by `on`, the above is an example using `on`*

Alternatively, in your case, you can probably just use the `click` function, which I find neater, but up to you:

```
$(".track").click(function(e) {   
    var dataTrack = $(this).attr("data-track");
});
```

**Fiddle:**

Using `on`:
http://jsfiddle.net/jUSUK/1/

Using `click`:
http://jsfiddle.net/jUSUK/2/

**More info on `attr`:**

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Figured out what the problem is, code is fine by the syntax with an icon isn't